Yarn rebuilds all packages when running the add command
I am having the following problem with Yarn
Whenever I run the yarn add or yarn remove command all previously installed packages are rebuilt


I have tried with other versions of Yarn but the problem persists.
Please let me know the reason and how to fix it, thanks.
Node version: 20.10.0
Yarn version: 1.21.1
OS: Windows 11
